# Can't access silverlight web service

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I have a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` that allows everything.

I use javascript to pop up a window from an aspx from the same server.

The aspx calls the web service but fails.

> silverlight System.Security.SecurityException: Security error. This
>   could be due to  attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way
>   without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is
>   unsuitable for SOAP services.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Any idea?

Comment: It should be called clientaccesspolicy.xml and make sure it is in the actual root of the website you are hosting on, not just where the app might be.

Comment: I mistyped that is the name of the file I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My servicereference.clientconfig was pointing to localhost instead of the deploy server :-(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the file you have configured "ClientConfig.xml" should be called "clientaccesspolicy.xml" and be in the root of the website.

[Here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-cross-domain-policy-file-snippet-intellisense.aspx) is a great post by tim heuer on using the clientaccesspolicy file.